# Ошибка при открытии базы данных

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

При добавлении базы данных к проекту, когда пытаюсь ее открыть вылазиет ошибка
"Не удалось найти ресурсы, соответствующие указанной культуре или нейтральной культуре.  Проверьте правильность внедрения или связывания "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.SqlViewSupport.xml" со сборкой "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer" во время компиляции, или убедитесь, что все необходимые сопутствующие сборки полностью подписаны и могут быть загружены.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68838794/12888024 Обновите Visual Studio до последней версии.